# How to fixed the scrollbar on the right of stage in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I add an scrollbar into a stage , I  want to fixed the scrollbar  on the right of stage, at first i want to  try to make it through css,but i can not find the style like "position:absolute", so i add a ChangeListener on stage,when stage resized,reset the  scrollbar's  LayoutX and  LayoutY,and yes ,it works,but when i maximized the stage，it not work，i add three listener on stage

```
 stage.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
                {
                    System.out.println("this is  height,newValue："+newValue.intValue()+"oldValue："+oldValue.intValue());
                }
            });

stage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                    System.out.println("current height"+stage.heightProperty().doubleValue());
                    System.out.println("current width"+stage.widthProperty().doubleValue());
                }
            });

  stage.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
                {
                    hBox.setPrefWidth(newValue.intValue()-30);
                    table1HorizontalScrollBar = findScrollBar( table1, Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
                    table1VerticalScrollBar = findScrollBar( table1, Orientation.VERTICAL);
                    table2.setPrefWidth(newValue.intValue()-table1.getWidth());
                    table2HorizontalScrollBar = findScrollBar( table2, Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
                    table2VerticalScrollBar = findScrollBar( table2, Orientation.VERTICAL);
                    bindValueProperty();
                    System.out.println("this is width ,newValue："+newValue.intValue()+"oldValue:"+oldValue.intValue());
                }
            });
```

when I maximized the stage, the console output looks like this:

[image: the result on console]

now,I can get the stage's newValue of width and height;
but on the stage ,the scroller still on the old position, like this

[image: the positon of scrollbar]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the correct layout for this job:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(scrollBar);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollBar, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollBar, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollBar, 0d);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

or for 2 `ScrollBar`s:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ScrollBar vScrollBar = new ScrollBar();
    vScrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    ScrollBar hScrollBar = new ScrollBar();
    hScrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    Region r = new Region();
    r.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    r.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));

    GridPane root = new GridPane();

    ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    c1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    ColumnConstraints c2 = new ColumnConstraints();
    c2.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
    root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(c1, c2);

    RowConstraints r1 = new RowConstraints();
    r1.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    RowConstraints r2 = new RowConstraints();
    r2.setVgrow(Priority.NEVER);
    root.getRowConstraints().addAll(r1, r2);
    root.addRow(0, r, vScrollBar);
    root.add(hScrollBar, 0, 1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```